# Receive WM_COPYDATA messages in a Qt app

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am working on a Windows-only Qt application, and I need to receive data from a Microsoft OneNote plugin. The plugin is written in C#, and can send WM_COPYDATA messages. How do I receive these messages in a C++ Qt app?

I need to:

- Be able to specify the "class name" a window registers as when it calls RegisterClassEx, so that I can make sure the plugin sends WM_COPYDATA messages to the correct window.
- Have access to the message id to check if it's WM_COPYDATA and lParam, which contains the COPYDATASTRUCT with the actual data. This information is passed in WndProc, but I am unable to find a hook where I can intercept these messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can all be handled within Qt:

1. Extend QWidget with a class that will capture the WM_COPYDATA messages:

   ```
       class EventReceiverWindow : public QWidget
   {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       EventReceiverWindow();

   signals:
       void eventData(const QString & data);

   private:
       bool winEvent ( MSG * message, long * result );
   };
   ```
2. Generate a GUID to set as the QWidget's windowTitle:

   ```
   EventReceiverWindow::EventReceiverWindow()
   {
       setWindowTitle("ProjectName-3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301::EventReceiver");
   }
   ```
3. Override winEvent to handle the WM_COPYDATA structure and emit a signal when you get it:

   ```
   bool EventReceiverWindow::winEvent ( MSG * message, long * result )
   {
           if( message->message == WM_COPYDATA ) {
               // extract the string from lParam
               COPYDATASTRUCT * data = (COPYDATASTRUCT *) message->lParam;

               emit eventData(QString::fromAscii((const char *)data->lpData, data->cbData));

               // keep the event from qt
               *result = 0;
               return true;
           }

           // give the event to qt
           return false;
   }
   ```
4. In another class, you can use this class to receive the message strings:

   ```
   EventReceiverWindow * eventWindow = new EventReceiverWindow;
   QObject::connect(eventWindow, SIGNAL(eventData(const QString &)), this, SLOT(handleEventData(const QString &)));
   ```

   ...

   ```
   void OneNoteInterface::handleEventData(const QString &data)
   {
       qDebug() << "message from our secret agent: " << data;
   }
   ```
5. And in the program that is sending the messages, simply [find the window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28VS.85%29.aspx) by the unique window caption. Here's an example in C#:

   ```
   private struct COPYDATASTRUCT
   {
       public IntPtr dwData;
       public int cbData;
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
       public string lpData;
   }

   private const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;

   [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
   static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

   [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
   private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

   private void sendMessageTo(IntPtr hWnd, String msg)
   {
       int wParam = 0;
       int result = 0;

       if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero )
       {
           byte[] sarr = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg);
           int len = sarr.Length;
           COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
           cds.dwData = IntPtr.Zero;
           cds.lpData = msg;
           cds.cbData = len + 1;
           result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, ref cds);
       }
   }
   ```

   then you can:

   ```
   IntPtr hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.zero, "ProjectName-3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301::EventReceiver");
   sendMessageTo(hwnd, "omg hai");
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a dummy window just for receiving that message with the Win32 API. I guess you won't have access to a Qt-Window's window proc, so this should be the easiest way.

You *could* (I wouldn't) also subclass the window by setting a new WndProc (with `SetWindowLong(Ptr)`, the window's handle can be obtained with `QWidget::winId()`). In this WndProc, you could just handle your specific WM_COPYDATA and pass all other window messages to the old WndProc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QWinHost](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/qwinhost.html) from Qt solutions to create a dummy window. Following [the guide](http://doc.trolltech.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-win32-in-qt-example.html) will show you how to specify your class name and check the event loop for your message.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not willing to pay... :( is there another way?

Comment: Actually Qt solutions has an LGPL license - you don't have to pay for a license.

Answer (score 0):

To handle messages your window receives, override your [QCoreApplication::winEventFilter](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcoreapplication.html#winEventFilter). If that doesn't work you can take a look at [QAbstractEventDispatcher](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qabstracteventdispatcher.htm).

For the class name you could try using [QWidget::winId](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#winId) along with Win32 API. I would try and find it for you but I can't right now, maybe try [GetClassName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I need "Set class name." Also, winEventFilter gives me the parameters MSG * msg, long * result, which does not include lParam, which contains the actual message sent with WM_COPYDATA.

Comment: upon further investigation, it looks like MSG is a structure that includes message id as well as lParam, so this solution is great. stackoverflow's security won't let me change my vote for your answer.

Comment: Also, this still doesn't solve the problem that I need to be able to SET the class name.

Comment: Since Qt is the one who registers your window, it doesn't seem likely that it's configurable. That's why I recommended to let Qt use whatever class name it chooses and use GetClassName in runtime to figure out what it is then use that in your plugin.