# Qt WinEvent - Never raised

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, message, mouseclick-event

I'm trying to get a mouse click event in Qt, this mouse click must be global, and must be received even if the mouse isn't over my app window, I saw in these links:

[Receive WM_COPYDATA messages in a Qt app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755196/receive-wm-copydata-messages-in-a-qt-app)

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/viewthread/8103

That I can get a message from Windows reimplementing the WinEvent. I have tried this and when debuging this event is never raised. Have I missed something?

here's a sample of my code:

```
bool WindowsUtil::winEvent( MSG * message, long * result )  {
  if (message->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN) {//never got here at all
    *result = 0;
    return true;
  }

  // give the event to qt
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Is it even possible to get an event (mouse) that has nothing to do with your application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it.

I used [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the initialization with [WH_MOUSE_LL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_mouse_llhook) as a paramenter for low level messages.
So, at the end, no Qt code was needed for  getting mouse events.

Comment: Using a low level mouse hook is a fairly drastic way to receive mouse messages that are not necessarily directed towards your window. A less severe way to implement the desired behavior would be to use the [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) API.